# my xcode 6.1 keep crashing when i resize or pin the view in storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, crash, autolayout

I think its the autolayout thing that keep me crashing?

I tried to add a view in the main view in my project
and when i tried to resize it .or pin it, it just crash 
I dont know how to do now..

> Application Specific Information:
>   ProductBuildVersion: 6A1052d
>   ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/IDEInterfaceBuilder/IDEInterfaceBuilder-6250/InterfaceBuilderKit/AutoLayout/IBAutolayoutFrameDecider.m:346
>   D etails:  "arbitrationUnit" should not be nil.

Comment: Try to Build->Clean, and delete Derived Data in project's Organizer window. If not help - delete storyboard and re-create it

Comment: but my storyboard is sooooo huge..i dont want to..

Comment: try to open storyboard as XML file and find arbitrationUnit and set to nil

Comment: i forgot to save it now my storyboard completely not working./.